# How to parallelize the scp command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, scp

I need to scp the files from `machineB` and `machineC` to `machineA`. I am running my below shell script from `machineA`. I have setup the ssh keys properly.

If the files are not there in `machineB`, then it should be there in `machineC`. I need to move all the PARTITION1 AND PARTITION2 FILES into machineA respective folder as shown below in my shell script -

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly PRIMARY=/export/home/david/dist/primary
readonly SECONDARY=/export/home/david/dist/secondary
readonly FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
readonly MAPPED_LOCATION=/bat/data/snapshot
PARTITION1=(0 3 5 7 9)
PARTITION2=(1 2 4 6 8)

dir1=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]} ls -dt1 "$MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)
dir2=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]} ls -dt1 "$MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | head -n1)

length1=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]} "ls '$dir1' | wc -l")
length2=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]} "ls '$dir2' | wc -l")

if [ "$dir1" = "$dir2" ] && [ "$length1" -gt 0 ] && [ "$length2" -gt 0 ]
then
    rm -r $PRIMARY/*
    rm -r $SECONDARY/*
    for el in "${PARTITION1[@]}"
    do
        scp david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/.
    done
    for sl in "${PARTITION2[@]}"
    do    
        scp david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$sl"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/. || scp david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/t1_weekly_1680_"$sl"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/.
    done
fi
```

Currently, I am having 5 files in PARTITION1 AND PARTITION2, but in general it will have around 420 files, so that means, it will move the files one by one which I think might be pretty slow. Is there any way to speed up the process?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I dont think there is much benefit to you making this concurrent, its only two hosts. If you had two thousand there might be a good case to make for the extra complexity -- else you're falling into a trap of over-engineering this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parallelizing SCP is counterproductive, unless both sides run on SSD's. The slowest part of SCP is wither the network, in which case parallelizing won't help at all, or disks on either side, which you'll make worse by parallelizing: seek time is going to kill you.

You say machineA is on SSD, so parallelizing per machine should be enough. The simplest way to do that is to wrap the first forloop in a subshell and background it.

```
( for el in "${PARTITION1[@]}"
do
    scp david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}:$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}:$dir2/t1_weekly_1680_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/.
done ) &
```

Comment: machineA is running on SSD's not sure about machineB and machineC.

Comment: And if you are saying parallelizing won't help at all. The way I am doing currently is the only way which is efficient? Or we can improve it slightly?

Comment: Rats, that means I'll have to give you an actual answer :)

Comment: And similarly I can do it for second for loop as well? They both are moving into same machine but in different folders..

Comment: sure, but why? there's nothing left to run in the foreground after that :) - btw, you'll also want to add a `wait` at the end of the script.

Comment: I see what you meant, Then how do I run my other for loop in the background as well?

Comment: I have had a situation where it was neither the disk bandwidth nor the network bandwidth that limited the performance. It was network latency. In that situation I got a factor of 3 performance boost by using GNU Parallel (see other answer).

Answer (score 3):

You could use GNU Parallel to help you run multiple tasks in parallel.

However, in your situation, it would appear that you're establishing a separate secure connection for each file transfer, which is likely quite inefficient indeed, especially if the other machines are not on a local network.

The best approach would be to use a tool that specifically does batch file transfer —  for example, `rsync`, which can work over plain ssh, too.

If rsync is not available, as an alternative, you could use `zip`, or even `tar` and `gzip` or `bzip2`, and then `scp` the resulting archives (then connect with `ssh`, and do the unpacking).

Comment: How to use GNU Parallel: https://gist.github.com/rcoup/5358786 and http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__parallelizing_rsync

Answer (score 0):

I've already had a problem with scp, two machines on the same network with Gigabit connection that were transferring very slowly over scp.

If you DO NOT need encryption, it will for sure help a bit to use ftp or nfs.

I found out that the problem was that one of the machines had slow RAM and the ssh encryption part was very demanding for this machine. Using ftp or nfs solved my problem, I went from 15-20 MB/s to 100+ MBps.

[EDIT]

I just found this which uses the excellent rsync instead of scp. Doesn't solve your entire problem but could help.

https://gist.github.com/KartikTalwar/4393116